# MySQL Join Query result if null in 2nd table

Tags: mysql

In my first table are the most informations.
The 2nd table can be filled after a time, so if there is nothing, i will get NULL or 0 back or something in cases.opened. But i dont know how to handle with the WHERE clause "AND cases.opened = 0" if there is nothing in cases table with that userid...

Thats my query

```
SELECT offers.case_id, offers.trade_id, offers.state, offers.amount, cases.opened FROM offers INNER JOIN cases ON offers.trade_id = cases.trade_id WHERE offers.user = '+pool.escape(userid)+' AND cases.opened = 0
```

So cases can be nothing with opened 0 from that user, but if there is nothing, i will get something back :/

Now i get nothing back, if cases is empty. But if something is in cases, i get correct infos back.

Please help me how to get also something back, if there is nothing in cases

I found out that this is working, thanks to the answer!

```
SELECT offers.case_id, offers.trade_id, offers.state, offers.amount, cases.opened FROM offers LEFT JOIN cases ON offers.trade_id = cases.trade_id WHERE offers.user = '+pool.escape(opskinsid)+' AND offers.state = 9 OR offers.user = '+pool.escape(opskinsid)+' AND offers.state = 3 AND cases.opened = 0
```

But it loads very very long time... around 14-18 seconds...
With my first query it was under 0.5secs...

Any ideas why? :/

In that last Query i check if the state in offers is 9, than give back result, or if the state is 3, the opened is 0 and something.
Cause if its state 3 in offers, there must be a row in cases

Answer (score 0):

If you use a left join, the row from the left table will be returned in any case even if there are no matching rows from the right table.

```
SELECT offers.case_id,
       offers.trade_id,
       offers.state,
       offers.amount,
       cases.opened
       FROM offers
            LEFT JOIN cases
                      ON offers.trade_id = cases.trade_id
       WHERE offers.user = '+pool.escape(userid)+'
```

Comment: Hm but i dont get anything back if there is nothing for that trade_id...
I want to get results back if opened = 0 or there is no row found. But i dont get anything back with the query :/ I only get something back if there is a row with same trade_id and opened = 0

Comment: @Reudiga: I'm not sure if I understand you. Have a look at my edit. Does that what you want?

Comment: Please check my Question again, i updated. I posted a query there, that works, but the loading time is very very long :/

Comment: @Reudiga: That completly changes the scope of your question... Anyway, try indexes on `offers(user, state)` and `cases(trade_id, opened)`. They might speed this up.

Comment: I put that query i mysql query optimizer, postet the result as answer! That working fast! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty strange literal you are testing for offers.user. No matter.

You want to use an Outer Join:

```
SELECT offers.case_id, offers.trade_id, offers.state, offers.amount,
       ifnull(cases.opened, 0) as opened
FROM offers OUTER JOIN cases ON offers.trade_id = cases.trade_id AND cases.opened = 0
WHERE offers.user = '+pool.escape(userid)+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that solution

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    ((SELECT
        offers.case_id,
        offers.trade_id,
        offers.state,
        offers.amount,
        cases.opened 
    FROM
        offers 
    INNER JOIN
        cases 
            ON offers.trade_id = cases.trade_id 
    WHERE
        offers.user = '+userid+' 
        AND offers.state = 3 
        AND cases.opened = 0) 
UNION
DISTINCT (SELECT
    offers.case_id,
    offers.trade_id,
    offers.state,
    offers.amount,
    cases.opened 
FROM
    offers 
LEFT JOIN
    cases 
        ON offers.trade_id = cases.trade_id 
WHERE
    offers.user = '+userid+' 
    AND offers.state = 9)
) AS union1
```

thats working very fast now :)

Thanks @sticky bit
His idea to mysql query optimizer gives that back :)